# Prevent direct access to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I'm new to web developemnt and I was wondering if it's possible to prevent to access directly to a method of the controller.

Let's say I have this method :

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   //do some stuff here
}
```

Basically I can access it via `siteaddress/controllerName/Delete?id=1` from browser, postman or whatever...

Is there a way to make this method a kind of "private" method, only accessible from the application ?

I'm using form identification (Identity). I also know I can use custom attribute to deny direct access but I don't want a redirection. Maybe "antiforgerytoken" is the solution but I'm not sure...

Comment: What do you mean "only accessible to the application"? What will be calling the method?

Comment: Ajax call from a view

Comment: Well then the best thing you can do is verify that the person calling the action method is authorized to do so, and that the object being deleted is in a state where you want to allow deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [NonActionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) ?

```
[NonAction]
public void Delete(int id)
{
   //do some stuff here
}
```

This will make the method non-accessible via HTTP, but available for C# code. If that's what you want.